# How to call multiple rest requests with Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios

I am new to React JS. I have read some examples of how to create client rest in Reactjs.
my questions - I get all courses and then I want for each course call another HTTP service. My code is below.

```
export default class Courses extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {courses: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8065/api/course/all')
        .then(response => {
            const courseList = response.data.map(c => {
                return {
                  id: c.id,
                  name: c.name,
                  previewBase64:c.previewBase64,
                  authors:
                     axios.get('http://localhost:8065/api/course/getAuthorsByCourseId/'+c.id+"/")
                    .then(res => {
                        const profiles = res.data.map(p => {
                            return {
                              name: p.name                       
                            };
                          })
                    })
                };
              })
              console.log(courseList);
              const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
                courses: courseList
              });
              // store the new state object in the component's state
              this.setState(newState);
        }); 
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <CourseList courses={this.state.courses}/>
        )
    }
}
```

my CourseList.jsx :

```
const courseList = (props) => (
    <Grid>
    <Row>
        {
            props.courses.map((course, i)=>{
                return  (
                <Col key ={i} lg={2} sm={8} xs={12} md={6}>
                    <div className="course-block">
                         <p>{course.name}</p>
                         <p>AUTHOR NAME WILL BE HERE </p>
                    </div>

                </Col>)
                }) 
            }                             
    </Row>
</Grid>
);

export default courseList;
```

This code works but I get "promise" for authors like that. 
{id: 7, name: "HTML", previewBase64: "", authors: Promise}

Comment: try await: `authors: await axios.get('http......`

Comment: What is inside your Author object?

Comment: Instead of `.then` after your authors call try `.subscribe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [axios.all](https://github.com/axios/axios#concurrency)

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8065/api/course/getAuthorsByCourseId/';

const p = Promise.all(response.data.map(({ id }) => axios.get(`${baseURL}${id}`)));

p.then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(e => {
  throw e;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this below, use this as a reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

```
async componentWillMount() {
        let data = await axios.get('http://localhost:8065/api/course/all').then(response => {
            return response
        })
        const courseList = data.map(c => {
            return {
                id: c.id,
                name: c.name,
                previewBase64: c.previewBase64,
                authors: await axios.get('http://localhost:8065/api/course/getAuthorsByCourseId/' + c.id + "/")
                    .then(res => {
                        const profiles = res.data.map(p => {
                            return {
                                name: p.name
                            };
                        })
                    })
            };
        })
        console.log(courseList);
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
            courses: courseList
        });
        // store the new state object in the component's state
        this.setState(newState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try refactor this way, Anyway it's better having just one API that return both courses and authors

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8065/api/course/all')
    .then(response => {

      const promises = response.data.map(c => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8065/api/course/getAuthorsByCourseId/'+c.id+"/")
        .then(res => { //for each course get the authors
            return res.data.map(p => {
                return {
                  name: p.name                       
                };
              });
        })
        .then(profiles => ({ id: c.id, profiles })); //keep a reference with the course
      });

      axios.all(promises, (allProfiles) => { //wait for all getAuthorsByCourseId are resolved
        const profileMap = allProfiles.reduce((map, profiles)=> {
          return map[profiles.id] = profiles.profiles;
        }, {}); // from array to map
        const courseList = response.data.map(c => {
          return {
            id: c.id,
            name: c.name,
            previewBase64:c.previewBase64,
            authors: profileMap[c.id],
          };
        }); //build the courseList with all data resolved
        const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
          courses: courseList
        });
        // store the new state object in the component's state
        this.setState(newState);       
      });
    }); 
};
```

Comment: it is not a problem to create one API which includes both courses and authors. but if I want to create API like microservices, should I separate it?

Comment: I think that for this use case it’s better to have one API, because courses and authors are very close  entities and you can serve all the information to the client with one request doing a simple join (is relational db), minimising load and network latency